# Ruby Gosu not able to find the background image

Tags: ruby, libgosu

```
 def initialize
 super 200, 135, false
 self.caption = "Gosu Cycle Example"
 @shape_x = 0 
 # Create and load an image to display
 @background_image = Gosu::Image.new("media/earth.png") #this is causing the error

# Create and load a font for drawing text on the screen
 @font = Gosu::Font.new(20)
 @cycle = 0
 puts "0. In initialize\n"
 end
```

I keep getting an error with the background image initialization. It keeps giving an error where it can't find the file specified. The image is in a folder called 'media' which is in the folder for the program.

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAR3R.png)

I had a similar issue with the 'require' but fixed it with 'require_relative'. I cannot find such a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give absolute Path:

```
/Users/{name}/.../media/earth.png
```

The above example is for a Mac.

Comment: That managed to fix it. So Gosu is unable to handle relative path with Windows? Really appreciate the help btw.

Comment: To be honest i don't have much experience on windows but in general its possible to give relative path depend how you lunch the ruby instance.

Answer (score 2):

Gosu does support relative paths, but they're **relative to the working directory where you're invoking the game from**, not relative to the source file. This might be what's tripping you up here!

For example, for the following directory structure:

```
game
 |--- src
 |     '--- main.rb
 '--- res
       '--- image.png
```

If you had the `game` folder as your working directory and ran `ruby src/main.rb`, then Gosu would be able to access the image relatively as `res/image.png`.

This means you'd have to execute your game from a particular working directory every time, but obviously that's not ideal.

Instead of using these awkward relative paths, it might be helpful to use `__dir__` along with `File.expand_path` to grab the absolute path to your directory which your script is running in, and concatenate onto that path, like this:

```
# Running from src/main.rb

File.expand_path(File.join(__dir__, "../res/image.png"))
# => "/wherever/game/res/image.png"
```

This is better than hardcoding an absolute path because your game would still work on somebody else's computer.

Comment: I modified the code to this:  @background_image = Gosu::Image.new(File.expand_path(File.join(__dir__, "../media/earth.png")))  But it gives the same error as before. The absolute path worked but I don't wish to use it for the reasons you specified. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Hmm, that should be OK... Try printing the path which `File.expand_path` returns and see if it looks correct to you.